# MongoDB (pymongo) $avg and $stdDevPop do not work inside $project, but they work perfectly inside $group

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to find the Average (`$avg`) and the Standard Deviation (`$stdDevPop`) in a collection, check if the Average value is larger than the Standard Deviation value, and, depending on this, use the larger one as a `optimalCredit` value .

If I use `$avg` and `$stdDevPop` inside `$group`, they work without issues, but, when I place them inside a `$project`, they return `Null`

I am really new to Mongo (yesterday morning I made my first query) so I know I must me understanding something wrong.

This is the code I came up with to compare the Average (`$avg`) and the Standard Deviation (`$stdDevPop`):

```
{'$match':
      {'charRange': 
          {'$gt': 0},
      'countPar': 
          {'$gte': 0}
},

{'$group':
      {'_id': 
          {'charRange': '$charRange', 'parNr': '$countPar'},
       'count': 
          {'$sum': 1}
      }
},

{'$project':
     {'optimalCredit':
          {'$cond':
              {'if':
                    {'$gt': [
                             {'$avg': 'credit'}, 
                             {'$stdDevPop': 'credit'}
                            ]
                    },
               'then': 
                    {'$avg': '$credit'},
               'else': 
                    {'$stdDevPop': '$credit'}
              }
          }
     }
},

{'$sort': 
     {'optimalCredit': -1}
}
```

This is the code I tested with to see if `$avg` and th `$stdDevPop` work and return data:

```
{'$match': 
     {'charRange': 
          {'$gt': 0},
     'countPar': 
          {'$gte': 0},
     }
},

{'$group': 
    {'_id': 
          {'charRange': '$charRange', 'parNr': '$countPar'},
           'creditAvg': 
                 {'$avg': '$credit'},
           'creditStdDev': 
                 {'$stdDevPop':'$credit'},
           'count': {'$sum': 1}
    }
}
```

This is what I am getting back when using `$project`:

```
{'_id': {'parNr': 7, 'charRange': 1500}, 'optimalCredit': None}
```

This is what I am getting if I remove `$project` and move `$avg` and `$stdDevPop` in `$group`:

```
{'_id': {'charRange': 1500, 'parNr': 7}, 'creditStdDev': 19.430788855719562, 'count': 9, 'creditAvg': 16.0}
```

Finally, this is the way it should look (using the numbers above):

```
{'_id': {'parNr': 7, 'charRange': 1500}, 'count': 9, 'optimalCredit': 19.430788855719562}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I needed to declare the average (`$avg`) and standard deviation (`$stdDevPop`) in the `$group` and then call these 2 from the `$project`

```
{'$match':
      {'charRange': 
          {'$gt': 0},
      'countPar': 
          {'$gte': 0}
},

{'$group':
      {'_id': 
          {'charRange': '$charRange', 'parNr': '$countPar'},
       'count': {'$sum': 1},
       'creditAvg': {'$avg': '$credit'},
       'creditStdDev': {'$stdDevPop': '$credit'}
      }
},

{'$project':
     {'count': '$count',
      'creditAvg': '$creditAvg',
      'creditStdDev': '$creditStdDev',
      'optimalCredit':
          {'$cond':
              {'if':
                    {'$gt': [
                             '$creditAvg', 
                             '$creditStdDev'
                            ]
                    },
               'then': '$creditAvg',
               'else': '$creditStdDev'
              }
          }
     }
},

{'$sort': 
     {'optimalCredit': -1}
}
```